# difficulty in numerical estimate of double integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I entered the following simple integral in mathematica:

```
NIntegrate[1/(0.01)^2*Exp[-(R - 1)^2/(0.01)^2] (1/Abs[z]^(1/3) - 1/(R^2 +z^2)^(1/6)),
            {R,0, 10000}, {z, -100000, 100000}]
```

and it returns 0, which is really strange. The result should not be zero. Now, instead of $\exp(-(R-1)^2/(0.01)^2)$, I try $\delta(R-1)$, after which the integral is

```
NIntegrate[DiracDelta[R-1]* (1/Abs[z]^(1/3) - 1/(R^2 +z^2)^(1/6)), {R,0, 10000},
             {z, -100000, 100000}]
```

which should definitely yield a non-trivial answer, but Mathematica still returns 0. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Are your integration limits actually 100000, or is that supposed to be `∞`?

Comment: That is infact supposed to Infinity, but to avoid problems at branches, I just use some large finite number instead. Shouldn't matter any ways as the integrand is rapidly decaying with increasing $z$.

Comment: You may have great loss of precision in your integration. Have you tried replacing the machine precision numbers (e.g. 0.01) with arbitrary precision ones, and increasing the `WorkingPrecision` setting?

Comment: At least the DiracDelta one should be relatively straightforward, right? But Mathematica just gives zero even for that which is what troubles me.

Comment: For the second integral: I don't think `DiracDelta` is meant to work with `NIntegrate`. If you `Integrate` it instead, you get an expression that evaluates to 1.29355 after applying `N`, and this agrees with the integral over `z` with `1` in place of `R`.

Comment: @titanium For both your integrals, replacing decimals with exact fractions, your large bounds with Infinity, using Integrate and then using N[result,32] gives nonzero results.

Answer (score 5):

Concerning your first integral:

If we take the freedom - as J.M. suggested in a comment - of chosing infinity instead of large numbers as limits of integration and allow for a general parameter "a" in the exponent (and in front) the double integral can be done explicitly:

```
a Integrate[Exp[-a (R - 1)^2] (1/Abs[z]^(1/3) - 1/(R^2 + z^2)^(1/6)), {R, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> a > 0]

(* Out[8]= - a ((Sqrt[\[Pi]]
   Gamma[-(1/3)] (Gamma[5/6] Hypergeometric1F1[-(1/3), 1/2, -a] + 
    2 Sqrt[a] Gamma[4/3] Hypergeometric1F1[1/6, 3/2, -a]))/(
 2 a^(5/6) Gamma[1/6])) *)
```

You can then insert a = 10^4 to get

```
%/. a -> 10^4 // N

(* Out[11]= 229.275 *)
```

This value should be very close to the original integral with the finite Limits of integration.

In your second integral you have tried to replace the exponential by  DiracDelta[]. 
But the replacement is not consistent, because the factor in front should be chosen accordingly:

```
2 Sqrt[ a/\[Pi] ]
  Integrate[Exp[-a x^2], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> a > 0]

(* Out[18]= 1 *)
```

Furthermore with that intention it is logical to let R->0 and calculate the z-Integral which gives

```
Integrate[(1/Abs[z]^(1/3) - 1/(R^2 + z^2)^(1/6)) /. 
  R -> 1, {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

(* Out[21]= -((Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[-(1/3)])/Gamma[1/6]) *)

% // N

(* Out[22]= 1.29355 *)
```